# Get concrete profile from request.user in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

I have abstract profile linked to the User:

```
class Account(models.Model):
   class Meta:
        abstract = True

    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, primary_key=True)
    patronic_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    # additional fields and methods
    def foo(self):
       print('account')
```

And I have multiple different roles and implementations - student, tutors, admins, etc.
I created a class for each of them, derived from the Account class.

```
class Teacher(Account):
    def foo(self):
        print('teacher')
    # ...additional fields and methods

class Student(Account):
        def foo(self):
            print('student')
    # ...additional fields and methods
```

Now I want to call `foo` method on the class object, like this:

```
@login_required
def index(request):
   request.user.account.foo()
```

But since `Account` class is abstract, there is no `request.user.account` M2M relationship.
I have `request.user.student`, `request.user.teacher` relationships, but I do not know the type of relationship.

Is there any way to get the concrete account of `request.user` User object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a property to your `User` model that inspects every subclass of `Account` and returns the first subclass that has a relationship to the user.

Something like this should work

```
@property
def account(self):
    for subclass in Account.__subclasses__():
        try:
            return getattr(self, subclass.__name__.lower())
        except DoesNotExist:
            continue
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this,

```
@login_required
def index(request):
    try:
        foo_result = request.user.account.foo()
    except AttributeError:
        foo_result = request.user.teacher.foo()
    ...
```

Comment: Currently, I am doing like this, yes. But the problem is I have 5 different classes and i have 5 nested try/excepts. It does not look right. I am looking for a better approach.